# How to get IE settings from C# code?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

So I need to know, are images, JS and flash enabled in user's Internet Explorer browser?
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plenty of ways to accomplish this, both Server Side and Client Side

**Windows Environment**

you have the `WebBrowser` control that will give you all the properties you need

**Web Environment**

*Client Side*

With a javascript Sniffer you can check all this, try it on [my own page](http://balexandre.com/sessions.aspx) and scroll down to the Javascript Browser Sniffer part (fell free to copy the code)

my javascript code is based on

> Eric Krok, Andy King, Michel Plungjan Jan. 31, 2002 from http://www.webreference.com/

*Server Side*

The `HttpbrowserCapabilities` can be found at `HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser` and it has all sort of properties ready to be used.

example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you might be able to get this information from the http header but im unsure

```
Request.Headers
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the document by Microsoft about accessing IE security settings from he registry keys [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182569).

The settings are located under the key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings

Answer (score -1):

for js you can use

```
 <noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
```

For flash have a look on: http://www.knowledgesutra.com/forums/topic/15669-javascript-check-for-flash/